# div stretching containing canvas

Tags: html, canvas, stretching

### Hi i am trying to have this:

`<div>

<canvas height="300px" width="200px"></canvas>

</div>`

I created javascript to render canvas, could someone advice how to stretch div according canvas size and if it is possible without javascript?? I already tried solutions for nested divs, but it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: Your code for height/width isn't valid. Try `style="height: 300px; width: 200px;"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different `display` for the containing `div` then things should work (see also [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpdgQ/)):

```
<div>
    <canvas height="300px" width="200px"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 2px solid blue; /* demo purposes */
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0;
}
canvas {
    background-color: khaki; /* demo purposes */
}
```

PS. The `line-height: 0` is there to make sure there appears no [space is rendered](http://jsfiddle.net/JPdeJ/1/) below the canvas. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15807833/419956).

Comment: regarding non validity please see http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_canvas.asp, it's not true that height and width properties are not valid...

Comment: yeah it works like this:  <div style="inline-block">
    <canvas style="height: 300px; width: 200px;"></canvas>
</div>

Comment: @anjalis Sure, using width/height via properties is also fine, but before [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10649567/revisions) it was neither using style nor attributes correctly. I've updated my answer accordingly. As far as I can see this should answer your question.

Comment: any news about this 5 pixel bottom margin ? I've got this exact problem. I'm gona ask the question.

Comment: see the related question here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807833/div-containing-canvas-have-got-a-strange-bottom-margin-of-5px

Answer (score 0):

if you can determine when your canvas size is changed then fire a event that will set the dimensions of the div dynamically as according to the changed dimensions of the canvas

Comment: It doesn't work  <div style="width:auto;height:auto;min-height:50px;min-width:50px">

Comment: Set the div to a different [display](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop), for example `inline-box`.

Comment: Ah yes, typo there. I've posted my suggestion as an answer with working fiddle and screenshot.