# Div containing canvas have got a strange bottom margin of 5px

Tags: html, canvas

I'm facing a strange problem.

in short :

When we put a canvas in a div and set the size of the canvas, the div is automatically 5px bigger than the canvas whereas I expect it to get the exact same size.

this question is a following of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10652093/1489009)
so I'll take the same example, the issue has been reproduced in firefox and in google chrome.
(didn't try other browsers)

```
<div>
    <canvas height="300px" width="200px"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div {
    border: 2px solid blue; /* demo purposes */
    display: inline-block;
}
canvas {
    background-color: khaki; /* demo purposes */
}
```

result (see the white space in the div) :

[image: result]

You can also see this exact same example (very simple) in [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jTFk/)

Why does this happen and how can we prevent it ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can prevent it from happening by adding `display: block` to the css for the canvas element.

i.e:

```
canvas {
    background-color: khaki; /* demo purposes */
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I'd like to know more about it,  if I don't set the display to block, what is the default display value and why does it make an empty space under the canvas ?

Comment: The space appears due to the inline formatting model. It's a complicated subject that I don't fully understand myself but you can read up about it [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inlineformatting) and [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/inline-format.html).

Comment: +1, you're right of course! The space at the bottom is actual whitespace being rendered. If you [set the `line-height` to 0](http://jsfiddle.net/kpdgQ/) the space also disappears.

Comment: @Jeroen Which whitespace, if we have `<div><canvas></canvas></div>`?

Comment: Interesting! So I was wrong in 2013 I guess, or not precise enough, as it seems a line of text gets inserted even if the tags follow eachother directly. It _is_ a line of text I think though, if you go `* { font-size: 100px; }` the white space does grow. - Not sure what precisely is going on.